# Sum of first n elements of a vector

Tags: r, vector, sum, subset

Let's say I have the following vector:

```
x <- c(5, 6, 3, 7, 5, 2, 6, 7, 5, 3, 1, 5, 6)
```

I would like to create a function with the parameter n that produces the sum of the first n elements.

Comment: Try `f1 <- function(x, n){ sum(head(x,n))}; f1(x,3)`

Comment: Or `f1 <- function(x, n){ sum(x[seq_len(n)])}; f1(x,3)`

Comment: There is also the `cumsum()` function which takes the cumulative sum of elements in a vector (useful if you plan to call your function for many values of `n`)

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
x <- c(5,6,3,7,5,2,6,7,5,3,1,5,6)
sumfun<-function(x,start,end){
  return(sum(x[start:end]))
}

x <- c(5,6,3,7,5,2,6,7,5,3,1,5,6)


> sumfun(x,1,3)
[1] 14
```