# R function to find count of elements before sum is above a threshold

Tags: r

I'm trying to recreate a function from [Sum of first n elements of a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412199/sum-of-first-n-elements-of-a-vector), but where this solution took an argument to sum first n elements of vector, I'd like an argument which is the threshold (including a default) the elements sum up to (or over).

After trying different `for` and/or `while` possibilities and searching StackOverflow, I've ended up here: unclear how to implement the threshold and set the `n_elements`.

I have this logic which returns `0` for the given vector. It doesn't seem the `n_elements = x[i] + 1` part is correct.

```
theFunc <- function(x, threshold = 5){
  n_elements = 0
  while (sum(head(x)) < threshold){
    n_elements = x[i] + 1
  }
  return(n_elements)
}
```

Call:

```
x <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7)
theFunc(x)
[1] 0
```

If the input is as above and the threshold is 5, then the function should return 6 (number of elements) because 0+0+1+1+2+3 = 7 and is above the threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple function without a loop is as follows:

```r
theFunc <- function(x, threshold = 5){
  sum(cumsum(x) < threshold) + 1
}
```

```r
x <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7)
theFunc(x)
[1] 6
```